# How to use callbacks to wait for two queries async node

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, callback, async.js

I am using the async module waterfall method for an sql query in node. How would I use a callback to send two sets of data to the next function. As in the first function that passes qryUpdateCheck and qryCheckDbl to the next. How would this properly be completed.

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        var requestUpdateCheck = new sql.Request([config]);
        requestUpdateCheck.query("Some qryUpdateCheck", function (err, qryUpdateCheck) {
            console.log('qryUpdateCheck', qryUpdateCheck);    
        });

        var requestCheckDbl = new sql.Request([config]);
        requestCheckDbl.query("Some qryRequestCheckDbl", function (err, recordset) {
            console.log('qryCheckDbl', qryCheckDbl);    
        });

        callback(null, qryUpdateCheck, qryCheckDbl);
    },
    function (qryUpdateCheck, qryCheckDbl, callback) {
        console.log('hi from second from qryUpdateCheck', qryUpdateCheck);
        console.log('hi from second from qryCheckDbl', qryCheckDbl);
        if ((qryUpdateCheck.length == 1) && (qryCheckDbl.length == 0)) {
            var requestUpdateLocID = new sql.Request([config]);

            requestUpdateLocID.query("Last qryUodateLocID", function (err, recordset) {
                console.log('qryUpdateLocID', recordset);
                callback(null, recordset);
            });
        } else if ((qryUpdateCheck.length == 0) && (qryCheckDbl.length == 0)) {
            var requestUpdateLocID = new sql.Request([config]);
            requestUpdateLocID.query("Insert qry", function (err, recordset) {
                console.log('qryUpdateLocID', recordset);
                callback(null, recordset);
            });
        }
    }
], function (err, result) {
  // result now equals 'done'
  console.log('done', result);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time the read the guide on how to answer a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer the question is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find [async.auto](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#auto) is better for situations like this. You pass it an object with a set of functions, and for each function, you can pass other function names as dependencies. It will then run any tasks that it can in parallel while making sure that functions with dependencies wait until they are all satisfied before being called. Its kinda like magic.

```
var request = new sql.Request([config]);
async.auto({
  // this runs in parallel because it has no dependencies
  requestUpdateCheck: function(callback) {
    request.query("Some qryUpdateCheck", callback);
  },
  // this also runs in parallel because it has no dependencies
  requestCheckDbl: function(callback) {
    request.query("Some qryRequestCheckDbl", callback);
  },
  // this waits for the first two functions and then executes
  requestUpdateLocID: ['requestUpdateCheck', 'requestCheckDbl', function(results, callback) {
    console.log('Results from requestUpdateCheck and requestCheckDbl', JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
    var qryUpdateCheck = results.requestUpdateCheck;
    var qryCheckDbl = results.requestCheckDbl;
    if ((qryUpdateCheck.length == 1) && (qryCheckDbl.length == 0)) {
      request.query("Last qryUodateLocID", function (err, recordset) {
        console.log('qryUpdateLocID', recordset);
        callback(err, recordset);
      });
    } else if ((qryUpdateCheck.length == 0) && (qryCheckDbl.length == 0)) {
      request.query("Insert qry", function (err, recordset) {
        console.log('qryUpdateLocID', recordset);
        callback(err, recordset);
      });
    }
  }]
}, function(err, results) {
  console.log('done:', err || results);
});
```

`results` will contain the data from all completed functions.

This is quite a simple example case, which some might argue [promises.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is better suited to. Personally, I find `async.auto` really helps when things get more complex. So for consistency, I use it for most async control flow and find that it handles most situations.

Comment: nice suggestion, this feels very much like gulp and dependent tasks.

Comment: I tried it and the results in the requestUpdateLocID comeback as undefined

Comment: ahh, you must be using async.js v2 - i'm on an older version... swap the callback and result arguments around in the function for `requestUpdateLocID` - it changed in v2 - i've updated the answer - it should be `(results, callback)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a nested parallel call. Here's a pseudo example using `setTimeout`:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        async.parallel({
            requestUpdateCheck: function(callback) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callback(null, 'UpdateCheck')
                }, 500)
            },
            requestCheckDbl: function(callback) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callback(null, 'CheckDbl')
                }, 500)
            }
        }, function(err, result) {
            // here the parallel op is done
            callback(err, result);
        }) 
    },
    function(result, callback) {
        console.log('hi from second from qryUpdateCheck', result.qryUpdateCheck);
        console.log('hi from second from qryCheckDbl', result.qryCheckDbl);
        callback(null, result);
    }
], function(err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'
    console.log('done', result);
});
```

Comment: I didn't actually test the code - could be that the name of callback should be changed. I'll play around with it.

Comment: @brandonscript that shouldn't matter that `callback` is used in various scopes here because *variable scope* will be used over the enclosing scopes `callback` value. IE the inner most enclosing function's scope will be used when there is a conflict.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'm in the middle of something but will take a look shortly.

Comment: it's not calling the callback in the 2nd function of the waterfall. after the 2 console logs

Comment: now it's passing the result as an error - sorry :) - i guess it should be passing on the `err` from within the query callbacks in the OP's original example

Comment: Yeah. A working version is in the Async docs - easy enough to copy and paste from there.